# Debug same shared project. Avoid "it is being used by another process"

Tags: dll, visual-studio-debugging

¿Is there any way I can have the same library across multiple projects, and debug them without the random "it is being used by another process"?

I know that is possible to add the DLL directly, but if I need to debug the library in both projects at the same time?

Comment: How did you add the dll reference? Does the library and two projects in the same solution or not? One issue is that whether the dll file has been re-compiled by one project during you debug the two projects, if so, I think it would share you that warning like "it is being used by another process" or have other conflicts.

Comment: Could you share the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry now I'm on vacation. The issue is: HelperLibrary.sln added in two different sln and then as reference.. debug them as the same time... and the first compiles just find, the second one complain with "HelperLibrary.dll is being used"

Comment: So it has three solutions(One library and two single executed projects A and B ), and then you add the dll file as the reference to the two projects in two different solutions, one issue is that how you debug the two projects at the same time. For example, if I add the dll as references to my project A and B(two solutions), I add breakpoints in the two project, I could debug B project during the breakpoint in A is hit. Do you set the "copy local=True" for this library reference in two projects? I could debug them in the same machine using the VS2015, if I have misunderstood it, let me know.